# DatagridView with variable number of columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to create a datagridview in C# (winform) with a variable number of columns. I have done this

```
dataGridView2 = _dm.CreateGrid();
```

where CreateGrid() is the following method:

```
public DataGridView CreateGrid()
    {
        DataGridView dtgr = new DataGridView();

        using (DbEntities db = new DbEntities())
        {

            foreach (Resource r in db.Resources)
            {
                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

                col.ValueType = typeof(string);
                col.Name = r.Description;
                col.HeaderText = r.Description;
                col.DataPropertyName = r.Description;
                dtgr.Columns.Add(col);
            }

        }

        return dtgr;
    }
```

Description is of type string. I don't see the datagridview in my winform. Where is the problem ?

Comment: place a panel on your form and put it inside that panel form code behind and set its dock to fill

Comment: How do you add the DGV to the form?

Answer (score 0):

I think `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` is causing the problem. Try using `DataGridViewColumn` instead. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need add your `DataGridView` to controls of the `Form`

```
dataGridView2 = _dm.CreateGrid();
this.Controls.Add(dataGridView2);
```

Why you create columns manually. `DataGridView` will generate columns automatically based on the columns/fields of the datasource, if you set `AutoGenerateColumns = true`

From MSDN [DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried to add the line this.Controls.Add(dataGridView2);

Comment: I still don't see the datagridview

Comment: @Boris, Please show a code in the question how your datagridview `dataGridView2` was initialized and used in the form? Does Form contain others controls? It is possible that other controls cover it. Try add `dataGridView2.BringToFront();` after adding it to the form controls